# Fail to deploy bare bone webapp to tomee 7.1.0 running openjdk 11

Tags: java, maven, tomcat8, java-11, tomee-7

I am planning to migrate a webapp from java 8/tomee 7.0.4 to java 11/tomee 7.1.0, but still unsuccessful.  So I write a barebone webapp with only one facelet page and one managed bean.  This works on java 10/tomee 7.1.0 but not java 11.  The errors are:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get Unsafe.defineClass
....
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String, [B, int, int, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.security.ProtectionDomain)
```

After some Googling, from http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Some-jars-in-TomEE-8-SNAPSHOT-are-not-Java-11-compatible-td4685162.html it seems that the problem originates from jaxb-impl. So I tried adding to pom.xml according to https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/08/29/migrate-maven-projects-to-java-11-jigsaw/ which failed.  I restored pom.xml and modified according to [Java 11 package javax.xml.bind does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist) which also failed.

This is for tomee server which is less popular.  But tomee 7.1.0 is based on tomcat 8.5 which should be much more popular.  I think the problem will still be the same.

Advice is appreciated and I think many people should have the same problem.

Comment: Note that your first link seems to be about TomEE-8-SNAPSHOT, not 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading your tomcat/tomee to the latest version, or downgrading your Java version as incompatible versions tend to fire these `NoSuchMethod/NoSuchFile` exceptions.

Could be that one technology is reliant on a certain other technology, and is aware of a certain API version, but you are trying to use a higher API version, which could be entirely different.

Another possibility is that tomee is not yet ready to work with java 11 at all (but this seems rather unlikely).

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded tomee 8.0.0-M1 (but this is an evaluation version) and it worked.  But I guess I'll wait for a production release before actually putting it to use.