# The package javax.xml.transform is accesible from more than one module

Tags: java, apache-fop

I'm trying to generate a PDF file from XML using Apache FOP, but there is a list of errors that appears when I import the needed packages.

```
    - The package javax.xml.transform.stream is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, 
     xml.apis
    - The package javax.xml.transform is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, xml.
     apis
    - The package javax.xml.transform is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, xml.
     apis
    - The package javax.xml.transform is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, xml.
     apis
    - The package javax.xml.transform.sax is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, xml.
     apis
    - The package javax.xml.transform is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, xml.
     apis
```

I have tried excluding the **xml-apis**, but it has no effect. Here are thr dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I also read that this problem appears after Java 8. Is there any other solution to this problem that does not include using Java 8?

Answer (score 5):

There are already several answers with respect to this error message:

- [Eclipse can't find XML related classes after switching build path to JDK 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094274)
- [The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286825)

In my case, I use the following exclusions on FOP in the pom file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>java.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>java.xml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

In my case, the problem occurred within Eclipse. Compiling the system using Maven showed no error messages. I had to update the Eclipse JRE to use the same parameters than Maven. The Eclipse issue is described in the second link above.