# Java 8 to Kava 11 migration issue

Tags: java, eclipse, migration, java-platform-module-system

On some imports I get the following exception:

```
The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml
```

**Example:**

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
```

I'm using Eclipse, OpenJDK 11. By using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to find out all places

`org.w3c.dom.Document` is available in the modulepath/classpath of my project only gives me *JDK library (JDK 11)* in result list.

I don't find any other jar/libraries present in classpath of the project listed.

So why am I getting above error if `org.w3c.dom` package is only referenced from *JDK runtime* (modulepath) only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286825/the-package-org-w3c-dom-is-accessible-from-more-than-one-module-unnamed-java)

Comment: Even a JAR on the classpath containing the package `org.w3c.dom` is invalid Java since Java 9 independent which classes it contains.