# The package javax.xml.stream is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Tags: java, compiler-errors, java-module

I have compilation error: `The package javax.xml.stream is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml`. Application with `maven install` build succesfully but it doesn't run as java application.

CTRL + SHIFT + T shows me that `javax.xml.stream` package is a part of JDK-11 (Modulepath) and `stax-api` (Classpath).
`stax-api` is a dependency of parent module which cannot be deleted. This problem occurs on Eclipse 2019-12, 2020-03, 2020-06 and IntelliJ and different versions of Java 11.

I tried so far to exclude javax.xml.stream for all dependencies within child
`<exclude>javax.xml.stream</exclude>`
but with no success.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The problem (and the solution) is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module

Answer (score 1):

> I tried so far to exclude javax.xml.stream for all dependencies within child
> `<exclude>javax.xml.stream</exclude>` but with no success.

Not sure how you did the exclusion? I would say it should be done in pom.xml. Similar to this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>A_GROUP_ID</groupId>
    <artifactId>AN_ARTIFACT_ID</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.xml.stream</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```