# The package javax.xml.xpath is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

[this is my pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTx0L.png)
i was trying to access the //XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();  but getting the issue like `The package javax.xml.xpath is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.xml`

can anybody suggest me how can i solve this issue please ?

Comment: Can you share me your import statements of the class where you are using `XPath`. Also add your `POM` to the question.

Comment: sure :    import javax.xml.xpath.Xpath, and i have attached my pom.xml in the question.

Comment: If Eclipse is your IDE, probably same issue as [Eclipse is confused by imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571046/eclipse-is-confused-by-imports-accessible-from-more-than-one-module)