# Can't run default tests but application works fine. Spring boot can't create entityManagerFactory bean, failing to load context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, testing

Application runs without any issues but I can't run default test file, created by Spring Initializr.

**Test file:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TicketShopApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/foobar
spring.datasource.username=foo
spring.datasource.password=bar
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>foobar</name>
    <description>foo</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**These exceptions are thrown:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
```

---

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: run on java9+ ?

Comment: @zlaval yes, sdk is java 10

Comment: java 9+ se no longer contains javax packages by default.
here is a relevant answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/48136912

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist

Comment: @zlaval thanks, worked