# No primary or default constructor found for class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, jaxbelement

I have been trying migrate a current spring based Java 8 application to Spring boot and Java 11.
Previously I used the Jaxb that came with Java but in Java 11 I need to import it explicitly since it is not part of the Java RT. But the same code is giving me the following exception, which I am not able to resolve.

```
2020-05-19 11:54:32.071 ERROR 49269 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3350) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2554) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:127) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:798) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.1.15.RELEASE.jar:5.1.15.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.34.jar:9.0.34]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

The relevant dependencies that I imported in my maven are as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have insured and excluded all the other dependencies that were bringing any other versions of jaxb libraries with them. Any assistance here would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

After the recommendation from @Klaus I changed the dependencies to Jakarta EE Deps and the dependency tree is as follows:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ validator ---
[INFO] com.abc.validator:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.abc:source-generator:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.17.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:3.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-security:jar:3.3.6:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jacorb:jacorb-omgapi:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.spec.javax.rmi:jboss-rmi-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.6.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring-boot:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-core-starter:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.25.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.2.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.34:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.34:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.16:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.4:test
[INFO] |     \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.2.13.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:2.0.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:2.0.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.11:jar:3.9.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- com.101tec:zkclient:jar:0.10:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.13:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:jar:test:2.0.1:test
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.sopware:sbb-papi:jar:3.4:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.200:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.2.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.15.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.19.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.15.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.34:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:9.0.34:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.14.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.activation:javax.activation:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.575 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-19T14:16:57+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is the method where I get this exception. It doesn't enter the method, the exception is thrown from within the signature.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/resource",
          consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
          produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
  public JAXBElement<MyObject> send(final JAXBElement<MyObject> myList,
                                                     @RequestParam("Id") final String Id) { 

//It doesn't reach this point 
... }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Have tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist

Comment: Hi Klaus, I tried the solution in the link you mentioned but it still gives the same error. I am editing the question with dependency tree. Maybe the problem is due to a conflict.