# Why failed to compile pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R?

Tags: maven, kettle

Why dose the release build fail? Pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.3-R is same problem.

Environmental information:

- maven version 3
- jdk 11
- mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

```
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:parse-version (set-doc-version-property) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:rootlocation (set-root-dir-property) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- license-helper-maven-plugin:1.27:check-license (check-license) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] Effective license file is [/usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/LICENSE.txt]
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- iterator-maven-plugin:0.5.1:iterator (javascript-dependencies_unpack-dependencies) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] ------ (dummy) org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.0:unpack-dependencies
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:add-resource (add-filtered-resources) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- license-helper-maven-plugin:1.27:bundle (bundle-license) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] License file [/usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/LICENSE.txt] will be added to [META-INF/LICENSE.txt]
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 [INFO] Copying 90 resources
 [INFO] Copying 1 resource
 [INFO] Copying 1 resource
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ kettle-core ---
 [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
 [INFO] Compiling 398 source files to /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/target/classes
 [INFO] /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/version/BuildVersion.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 [INFO] /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/version/BuildVersion.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 [INFO] /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/plugins/SupplementalPlugin.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
 [INFO] /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/plugins/SupplementalPlugin.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/Result.java:[32,33] package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist
 [ERROR] /usr/src/app/src/pentaho-kettle-9.0.0.2-R/core/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/core/Result.java:[65,2] cannot find symbol
   symbol: class XmlRootElement
 [INFO] 2 errors
```

Who can help me?

Comment: I know.  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist)

Comment: xmmm, kettle moved to maven. nice. Last time it was ivy

Comment: I beleive jdk11 removed package javax.xml (jee actually related packages and xml one of them). Add some implementation to build.

Comment: Such huge project really hard to upgrade to use jdk11 easy. Project pentaho-kettle still on jdk8

Answer (score 0):

Look at main pom.xml like
https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/pom.xml

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

Use jdk8.

*package javax.xml.bind.annotation does not exist* because if I ain't mistaken, it is moved to jee with removal from jdk core since jdk9