# Solution to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter step-by-step

Tags: java, maven, java-11, openjdk-12

I'm trying to connect SQL Server to Eclipse and I'm getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

After few days of looking into the topic it all boils down to removal of module javax.xml.bind in Java 11 (I have JDK12, using JavaSE-11). I am asking if anyone can help me in step-by-step solution how to resolve this. There are many answers where is said - add module  or   adjust dependency in Maven, but I couldn't find actual way to do that in form of - go to this file, edit it, replace with this... etc.
Also, I've found 
https://search.maven.org/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api/2.2.9/jar as a patch but I'm not sure if it's of any use since Maven is foreign to me.

I hope I have been clear. Any help is very much appreciated.

Stay safe, everybody!

Comment: Well, what build tool are you using? Maven/Gradle/Ant...? Just add a dependency to your build file for that library.

Comment: try this solution it works.     https://stackoverflow.com/a/52502208/7042380