# Error occurred during performing CRUD operation using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found.

guys please help me with this.

Comment: Are you using Java 11?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to java version which is greater than java 8 which is causing this issue.
Refer this post for fix:

[Java 11 package javax.xml.bind does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

Your error may be due to the Jaxb library that has been removed from java 9 onwards, if you use maven add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Or read this article https://www.jesperdj.com/2018/09/30/jaxb-on-java-9-10-11-and-beyond/