# bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8

Tags: java, bootclasspath

I am upgrading my application from java 1.8 to java 11 When I try to build using ant 1.10.8, my build fails but I also see a warning

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
```

I have set
`source=1.8` and `target=1.8`
in build.xml `javac` ant task

```
D:\Build>java -version
java version **"11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS**
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS, mixed mode)
D:\Build>javac -version
javac 11.0.7
```

Am I missing anything?  If Im not wrong, I need to set the bootstrap class path but I am not sure how to do it in ant build.xml file.
I also get below error

```
cannot find symbol [javac] import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
```

Please help

```
    **Note:** Im using javax.xml.ws, javax.xml.bind, javax.activation in my project
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this post ([Java 11 package javax.xml.bind does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist)) :

```
java.xml.bind (JAXB) - REMOVED

Java 8 - OK
Java 9 - DEPRECATED
Java 10 - DEPRECATED
Java 11 - REMOVED
```

Currently, I'm trying to find a solution with Maven to warn when a deprecation occurs.

I hope this answer can satisfy you

Comment: One way to get rid of this warning is to add **release** attribute in your javac ant task.
It will not show up again. e.g. `<javac release="8" encoding....`