# Spring Cloud Data Flow Local Server Jar - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

Recently I updated my JDK from 8 (1.8_275) to 11 (openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04)

While I am trying to launch [SCDF](https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/1.7.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar) local server using

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar
```

It had no issues at all while I used JDK 8. But with JDK 11, I am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

I looked [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/2038) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j). Even trying (with --add-modules java.xml.bind):

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar --add-modules java.xml.bind
```

results in the same error as mentioned above.

I understand, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist), it is removed in JDK 11. But What I am missing here? I mean how can I make it work or what is work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an ancient and deprecated version of SCDF. The 1.x version of SCDF has reached EOL/EOGS, as well. In particular, the version you're using is >2yrs old.

Please upgrade to the 2.x version. The latest GA is at 2.7.0.

Check out the [getting-started](https://dataflow.spring.io/getting-started/) guide and the [release blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/12/02/spring-cloud-data-flow-2-6-4-and-2-7-0-released) for more details.

Comment: Wow. This is exactly I was missing. But still wondering why the links are changed. Thanks a lot anyway. !

Answer (score 0):

You could try running without internet connection. They didn’t update the pre-built jars properly and it must be behind a firewall also. Try kubernetes too.