# From Java 10 to Java 11 "boot layer Module java.xml.bind not found", but nobody calls java.xml.bind

Tags: java, java-11

I'm porting a big Java project from Java 1.6 to Java 11, with many difficulties I'm arrived to Java 10, solving a lot of problems concerning java.xml.bind, also passing to jakarta.xml.bind and choosing a complete different set of libraries, the following:

```
activation.jar
commons-math-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
edtftpj.jar
gfe.jar
istack-commons-runtime-4.0.1.jar
jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.1.jar
javax.mail-1.5.5.jar
javolution-5.5.1.jar
jaxb-core-3.0.2.jar
jaxb-impl-2.3.1.jar
jaxb-runtime-3.0.2.jar
jcommon-1.0.16.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
jrntgen.jar
jrntspe.jar
junit-4.5.jar
log4j-1.2.15.jar
sdl.jar
spiffy-with_source-all-0.05.jar
SuperCSV-with_src-1.52.jar
txw2-3.0.2.jar
xstream-1.3.1.jar
```

Passing from Java 10 to Java 11, I have the following error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
> java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

It is really strange because searching in the project, it seems nobody is calling something on java.xml.bind anymore.
Any idea?

Comment: make sure your application server / web container are compatible wih jdk 11 for example glassfish 6 does not but 6.1 are but it it still RC

Comment: thanks but its a standalone desktop application

Comment: you welcome and sorry for my missunderstanding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 11 package javax.xml.bind does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist)

Comment: I don't think so, because I've already done everything passing from Java 1.6 to java 10, and now in my project there aren't reference to java.xml.bind, this is clear from a search in eclipse in any resource, also jars

Comment: You're JAXB dependencies are inconsistent: you have three different versions on your class path.