# After migration of my jaxb code generator to jakarta, the unmarshalled xml is different

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin, jakarta-migration

After migrating jaxb dependencies to ones which use jakarta as detailed here: [Java 11 package javax.xml.bind does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502189/java-11-package-javax-xml-bind-does-not-exist) I am observing something strange.

I am using `jaxb2-maven-plugin`, `version 2.5.0`, which has one dependency `xercesImpl 2.12.2`.
The `pom.xml` has direct dependencies on `jakarta.activation-api 1.2.2` & `jakarta.xml.bind-api 2.3.3` and transitive
dependencies on the `org.glassfish.jaxb jaxb-runtime 2.3.8`.

When I upgrade the `jakarta.xml.bind-api` to `3.0.1` and also try and upgrade the glassfish implementations, everything is generated seemingly correctly but the resulting xml is very different from what it was before.

The resulting XML has some peculiarities, for example it now contains the following mysterious tags

- any
- name
- additionalName
- otherAttributes
- declaredType
- scope

Where could these be coming from?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and examples of the before and after outputs.

Comment: I added some requested details, I will strive to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Do you target jaxb jakarta's package based ?

I don't know much about `jaxb2-maven-plugin` (which is probably codehaus maven plugin) but the dependencies listed above are the javax based package dependencies.

The jaxb dependencies did the jakarta move in v3 (jakartaee9, jdk8 based) and then in v4 they drop jdk8 support (jakartaee10 and jdk11 based).

If you want to generate java classes with jakarta's XML annotation, you should see if there's an updated version of the plugin that support this.

Another option is that you can try using the [jaxb-tools maven plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools) : it should be easy to switch from one plugin to another since they share some config parameters.

One note :

- v2 is for jaxb 2.3
- v3 is fof jaxb 3
- v4 is for jaxb 4 and requires jdk11 as minimal runtime